# How to set variable back to original in python loop

Tags: python

I use python with selenium and pyautogui for image recognition. In this code I'm looping image searching, when the image is on screen it should type Hi and then wait 20 seconds and set the variable back to original value,then search for the image again. It works except it does not set the variable to original again and keeps writing Hi even the image is not on screen. Thanks for any help.

```
    for i in range(0,20000):
    time.sleep(2)
    global enjoy1
    enjoy1 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('images/enjoy.png')
    enjoy1
    print(enjoy1)
    if enjoy1 == None:
        print("it is None")
    else:
        pyautogui.click(856, 816)
        pyautogui.typewrite('Hi') 
        pyautogui.click(1184, 816)
        time.sleep(20)
        enjoy1 = None
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your given code into a text file and reproduce the problem.

Comment: First of all, you never save the original value of the global variable.  Second, you specifically set it to **None**, but immediately overwrite that value with the next iteration's call to **locateOnScreen**.  Since you haven't bothered to show us the output you get, we don't have enough clues to work.

Comment: Ok sorry, there was actually nothing wrong in the code, just the image was somewhere I could not see it but pyautogui could so I thought the code is wrong, thanks for help.